# Flutter Firestore Wait untill all data read

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, e-commerce

i am trying to build an e commerce app. I got stuck while i was trying to build shopping cart. I read ids of product from cart collections and read products by those ids. Need to wait untill all product models are read and then loading state should turn false. But i can read only ids in cart and state turn false. When it happens, cart looks still empty even there is something in it. How can i solve this issue? I could not grab the idea of asynchronous function i guess. Thanks.

Read data from carts collection;

```
   Future <void> yukleme () async

  {

CollectionReference cartReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("carts");

 DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await cartReference.doc("1").get();

 cart_model = Cart_Model.fromJson(snapshot.data());

 print(cart_model.product_ids);

 setState(() {

   loading = false; // it turns false when cart model is done but product models havent read
 });

 return;

}
```

Cart model which contains id and product models in it.

```
Cart_Model.fromJson (Map<String, dynamic> snapshot)
  {
    product_ids = snapshot["product_ids"].cast<String>() ;
    if (product_ids.length > 0 && product_ids != null )
    {
      product_ids.forEach((String id) {
        productReference.doc("$id").get().then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
          ProductModel productModel = ProductModel.fromJson(snapshot.data());
        });
      });
   
          }
  }
```

Here where i call yukleme() function;
class _CartState extends State {

```
  bool loading = true;
  Cart_Model cart_model;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    if(loading == true)
    {
      yukleme();
    }
     ...................
```

Comment: Where and how did you call `yukleme()` ?

Comment: Tried to call initstate and before building widget.

Comment: i've edited my post

Comment: Does `Cart_Model.fromJson()` return something ? Seems it return nothing, so `cart_model` is null in this case

Comment: Thats why i asked the question. How can i wait untill cart_model and product_model read all data from firestore ? I tried to use setstate with loading boolean but didnt work

Comment: But nobody knows structure of your product and cart models.  `Cart_Model.fromJson` just retrieving products inside, but returns nothing . For now, i do not know how to create your `Cart_Model`